# vb.net getting dataset into datagrid

Tags: vb.net

With the code below is there anyway I could get the data from the dataset into a datgrid instead of setting up all those text boxes.Any help appreciated.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String



    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\databases\AddressBook.mdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("OPEN FOR THE DAY")
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts"

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "owltime")

    txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtSurname.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(2)
    address1.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(3)
    address2.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(4)
    address3.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(5)
    postcode.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(6)
    phone.Text = ds.Tables("owltime").Rows(0).Item(7)


    MsgBox(" CLOSED FOR THE DAY")


    con.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: are you trying to find out how to add a datagrid to your aspx page and bind the data to it?

Comment: Hi Attila thanks for reply.I have placed a datagrid on my form and when I run it I get the contents of the address book.But what I am trying to work out if there is a way that I could use sql to manipulate the dataset from within my code as opposed to using the sql data query builder that comes with the program...hope this nakes sense...Jim

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Answer**

You can just have a datagrid on the aspx page and then bind your datatable to it, like this

In your aspx page

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgrid"></asp:DataGrid>
```

In your code behind, replace your text box assignments with this:

```
dgrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("owltime")
```

**Windows Forms Answer**

Place a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview) control onto the Form and set the Name property to dgrid. You can change this value to something that makes more sense, but we have to reference this when binding the data table to it.

In your Button1_Click sub, replace your text box assignments with this:

```
dgrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("owltime")
```

To read more about the DataGridView's DataSource property, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource).

Comment: Hi Attila,thanks for your reply.I noticed you mentioned ASP but mine is not a webpage it's an ordinary form in VB10 connected to a database.The idea is to get VB to take the results of my SQL query and place the results into the datagrid an object whose function is to display data from a dataset/database.I was just wondering if this is possible with the existing program above. I have tried dropping a grid onto the form but cant see how to relate the grid to the existing code to deposit the results of the query into.Hope this make sense many thanks,any suggestions appreciated.Thanks again Jim

Comment: Oops. I didn't realize this was a Windows Forms application. Lucky for you, the steps to bind your datatable with the datagridview is similar and a little easier. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi Attila..Thanks for the reply :) Sorry about that I should have made that clearer early on.I keep getting mixed up because I am having a go at PHP as well as VB so I keep getting my wires crossed.Many thanks for your help.Jim